# Modified value in a function is not seen in another function

Tags: javascript, scope, settimeout

In the following code, check executes first and sets this.canClick to false. Then resetClick sets this.canClick to true after this.clickDelay seconds. However, the change is not seen in when check is called again. I logged the value of this.canClick in both functions: resetClick logs true, then check logs false for the same variable.

```
this.resetClick=function(){
    this.canClick=true;
};
this.check=function(){
    if (isMouseDown&&this.canClick==true){
        if (mouse.x>=this.x-this.sizex/2 && mouse.x<=this.x+this.sizex/2 && mouse.y>=this.y-this.sizey/2 && mouse.y<=this.y+this.sizex/2){
            this.text=this.callback();
            this.canClick=false;
            setTimeout(this.resetClick, this.clickDelay);
        }
    }
};
```

I don't believe it is a scope problem, because both are member functions of the same object and are modifying a property of that object. Also, in case you're wondering, that is a function to check if a button is clicked, and do "debouncing" so you don't click the same button twice by mistake.
EDIT: Important missing information: If I just call resetClick, without using setTimeout, it works.

Comment: The method you are calling with `setTimeout` is run outside of the object scope, so `this` will only refer to the global window object at the time the method is executed (and that means `this.canClick` will be `window.canClick` actually). Use a _closure_ to preserve the value of `this` inside the object. (Do some research, if you don’t know what that means.)

Comment: Thank you, @CBroe . Would you please submit an answer, so the solution is more visible to whoever visits this page?

Comment: By seconds, I supposed you mean milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a scope issue.
`this` inside the function does not refer to the object which will contain the function later.
You should bypass it with this one simple trick (tm): use an alias for `this`

```
var that = this;
this.resetClick=function(){
    that.canClick=true;
};
this.check=function(){
    if (isMouseDown&&that.canClick==true){
        if (mouse.x>=that.x-that.sizex/2 && mouse.x<=that.x+that.sizex/2 && mouse.y>=that.y-that.sizey/2 && mouse.y<=that.y+that.sizex/2){
            that.text=that.callback();
            that.canClick=false;
            setTimeout(that.resetClick, that.clickDelay);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you are calling with `setTimeout` is run outside of the object scope, so `this` will only refer to the global window object at the time the method is executed (and that means `this.canClick` will be `window.canClick` actually).

Use a *closure* to preserve the value of `this` inside the object.